# Formulating sequences in particular ways

Tags: number-sequence

Let's have the following sequences:

```
772,6772,59404,521092,?
298,2614,22930,201142,?
```

What comes next, where the question marks are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values:

> 4571019
>  1764418

Theory:

> Multiply by 8.772 and round. Don't know the significance of that number. Unicode &#8772; is "≄" and it's called "Not Asymptotically Equal To", which I guess could somewhat make sense here because those two sequences are not asymptotically equal, but meh.

Comment: @ Heap Overflow, your first sequence should be  4571020.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Hmm, why accept it then? New here, don't know how this works :-). I added my theory, if that's not correct I'd say unaccept it. I don't get your number.

Comment: @ Heap Overflow 3*521092+201142=1764418; 8*521092+2*201142=4571020

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Ok with that rule I get all your numbers from the start numbers. Then I'd say my answer is totally wrong. Should I just delete it?

Comment: Do as you please.

Comment: Bah, error "You cannot delete this accepted answer"